# Fetching the value of variable stored in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to fetch the output of a variable stored in a file in another shell script.
Example:

```
cat abc.log
  var1=2
  var2=2
  var3=25
```

I am writing a script to fetch the value of `var3`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And where is your script ?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F= '$1 ~ /^[[:space:]]*var3/  { print $2 }' abc.log
```

Set the field delimiter to = and then where the line contains "var3", print the second field.

Alternatively, you could:

```
source abc.log
```

and then:

```
echo $var3
```

Comment: Fair point @DavidC.Rankin. I have amended the answer

Comment: My bad -- you gotta fix it again, you need `$1 ~ /^[[:space:]]*var3/ ` (sorry) -- unless you do `$1=$1` in a rule above to force `awk` to recalculate the fields removing the leading whitespace.

Comment: Yeah. It's difficult to tell if that space before the variables in the example are intentional or not

Comment: Since I messed you up, I went ahead and edited it for you `:)`

Comment: This won't work if the value of the variable contains `=` character(s).

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` you can isolate `25` with particularity with:

```
sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*var3=/s/^[^=]*=//p' file
```

**Explanation**

This is the general substitution form `s/find/replace/` with a matching expression preceding it. The total form is `/match/s/find/replace/`. The option `-n` suppresses the normal printing of pattern-space and the `p` at the end tells `sed` to print the line where the match and substitution took place. Specifically,

- `/match/` locates a line with any number of preceding whitespace characters followed by `var3=`. The POSIX `[:space:]` character class matches any whitespace,
- the `/find/` is all characters anchored from the `'^'` beginning that are not the `[^=]` character and then match the literal `'='` character, and finally
- the `/replace/` is the empty-string leaving the `25` alone which is printed.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*var3=/s/^[^=]*=//p' file
25
```

Comment: Alternatively, just `sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*var3=//p' file`. No need for the address (`/match/`) here.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin - yes, that will work, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A `grep` one-liner, if your `grep` has support for Perl-compatible regular expressions (the `-P` option; not all `grep`s support that)

```
grep -Po '^\s*var3=\K.*' abc.log
```

or,

```
grep -Po '^\s*var3=\K.*' abc.log | tail -n1
```

in order to get the last value of the `var3`, if multiple `var3`s is a possibility.